# Why we need a Thread.sleep with two parameters

Tags: java

Since two parameters of Thread.sleep(long mills, int nanos) are used to define timeout.Why we need the second parameter?Shall we just invoke Thread.sleep(long mills) and increase value of its parameter?If no,what the special point with two parameters?

Comment: Exact duplicate found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of the two-argument `Thread.sleep()` is to allow you to specify sleep times in submillisecond intervals on systems that support that kind of resolution.

There would be no way to specify, e.g. a half a millisecond (500,000 nanoseconds) otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

a nano is less than a milli so this allows for **more** precision